# PHP date get microsecond precision to match MySQL column datatype

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column defined as the following in MySQL:

```
some_ts DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000'
```

Normally I'd use PHP's `date()` function with something like `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` but that will leave the microsecond number at a default. Is there a way to use `date()` to give me that as well so I can reflect it in the database?

Comment: Maybe the manual has something about microseconds? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Not an answer, but 0000-00-00 is not a valid date in any reality. Use NULL if you want a placeholder that means "no value here."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `date()` method by definition formats a unix timestamp, which only tracks time down to the second. You could use `DateTime::format()` to get current microseconds:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$ts = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
var_dump($ts); // 2018-01-04 01:28:33.12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the output of `microtime()` and append it to the `date()` call like this.

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s.").(explode('.', explode(' ', microtime())[0])[1]);
```

Output:

```
2018-01-04 10:28:17.226338
```

**Note:** for anyone that's skeptical about the performance of this; it performs about 33% faster than using `new Datetime()`.

Comment: *shrug* ... seems a feasible method to me. SOMETIMES some of us dont wanna use DateTime!

Comment: Oh boy! Micro-optimizations! I can't wait to show everyone the dozens of nanoseconds I saved with this bad boy!

Comment: @Sammitch tens of dozens!! Now go show all of your friends.

Comment: Too late. I'm a few billion nanoseconds in debt from typing that first comment. **OH SHIT, now I'm billions** ***DEEPER!*** [gets taken away to time-jail]

Comment: @Sammitch Had you used my code, you wouldn't be in this mess! Now I hope you take some time and reflect on the poor choices you've made here today. Also, https://i.imgur.com/gdrNjwC.jpg

Comment: I think this is a good solution when you just need to get the current microtime. My only suggestion is that you could remove one of the `explode` calls:

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . explode(' ', microtime()[0])`

Comment: @BrileyHooper `microtime()` always produces a leading `0.` so the second explode removes it.

Comment: @BrileyHooper No worries :)